# Why is there a lone pair in thionyl fluoride?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure

Why is there a lone pair in $\ce{SOF2}$? I drew its structure, which according to me should look like this:

[image: structure of thionyl fluoride]

Why is there a lone pair on sulfur? Isn't its octet complete? If yes, why should it expand its octet and gain more electrons?

Comment: How many valence electrons did S have in the first place?

Comment: @Ivan Oh you're right! S has 6.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to write a Lewis structure, I suggest you start from considering how many valence electrons each atom has. In your case, you would have:

S = 6
F = 7; total = 14
O = 6

The final total would be 14 + 6 + 6 = 26. The structure you guessed for is correct, sulfur is the central atom. You start by drawing a single bond per each atom, getting something like this:

```
F
|
S–O
|
F
```

Then, you can draw a double bond for oxygen:

```
F
|
S=O
|
F
```

If you do the math, by counting the electrons that you put in the previous structure, you would have 2 + 2 + 4 (two S-F bonds and a S=O) = 8.
Then we will add in the lone pairs: three on each halogen, two for oxygen, and one for sulfur. Therefore we add 3 × 2 × 2 = 12 electrons (three lone pairs on each fluorine) plus 4 electrons on O (the two lone pairs), and we have a total of 24. The final 2 , adding up to 26, come from the lone pair on sulfur.

This makes sense because sulfur is in period 3, so it is possible for it to have more than 8 electrons: in other words, the octet rule applies not only for 8 electrons, if that makes sense.

Comment: A much, much better description would use partial charges at the sulfur and oxygen and a single bond instead. A double bond would require d-orbitals from sulfur, a theory that hat been disproved. This has been discussed on our platform a couple of times. In any case, following the octet rule is usually safer than expecting 'octet expansion' (because the latter is wrong).

Comment: You are right, thank you for catching that! Do you have any references about what you said? :)

Comment: See for example https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/why-is-the-bond-order-in-the-so%e2%82%83-molecule-1-33-and-not-2