# S-O bond length in SO2 and SO3

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

> Question: which molecule out of $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{SO3}$ has larger $\ce{S-O}$ bond length?

Both are $sp^2$ hybridised. Since $\ce{SO3}$ has more bond pair - bond pair repulsions, shouldn't $\ce{SO3}$ have more $\ce{S - O}$ bond length so it can reduce repulsion?

Comment: I looked it up and $\ce{SO3}$ does have a slightly shorter bond than $\ce{SO2}$ which is indeed unusual. You should maybe add that fact to your question and you might draw a little more attention because your reasoning seems good to me.

Comment: While the question itself may not be too related, the *answer* seems to answer exactly what OP is asking about.

Comment: Also related: [molecular orbitals of $\ce{SO3}$](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/14232/7475)

Comment: Maybe we used the same book. There is a question about arranging 4 molecules in decreasing order of S-O bond length. In the hint given, the author says to apply bents rule for SO2 and SO3.