# Why is Sulfur Trioxide has SP² hybridization?

Tags: bond, orbitals, hybridization

When I google what is the type of hybridization in SO₃ it gives me "SP² hybridization". The problem I have is why does it has the above hybridization when it has 3 double bonds with the oxygen atoms.

For example, take CO₂. It has just 2 double bonds with oxygen, and it has SP hybridization. it has two π bonds that are not hybridized, and 1 P orbital hybridized with the S orbital. However, SO₃ has 3 double bonds and if it has SP² hybridization (which means only S and P orbitals participated in making hybrid orbitals) how does it has 6 bonds altogether (there is only 1 S orbital and only 3 P orbitals). SO₃ has three π bonds but, and it still has SP² hybridization (how did it get more than 3 P orbitals which are free or hybridized)

From my understanding hybridization occurs to minimalize the repulsion in electrons in orbitals. So, these S and P (D orbitals sometimes) orbitals make an intermediate orbital so that they can create bonds. Why and how does Sulfur Trioxide has SP² hybridization when it contradicts both of these behaviors I mentioned above?

Sorry in advance if my English is not that good.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/is-the-s-o-bond-strength-in-sulfur-trioxide-or-sulfite-anion-larger

Comment: @Mithoron I read the answer. From what I understand it is better to determine the hybridization using the shape of the molecule, than considering the way the bonds of these molecules have bonded (considering the number of π and σ bonds). Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @Mithoron Also is it okay to call the double bonds in SO₃ as π bonds?

Comment: Your "hybridization" is irrelevant. Geometry of a molecule is important. There's no double bond in SO3 - all of them have limited π character.